# How to simulate a n-p-n bjt using Cadence Virtuoso?

Tags: bjt, simulation, cadence

I had been simulating CMOS transistors using Virtuoso, in which I had used ami06n as model and NCSUanalogParts as library. But for a BJT, when i tried simulating through ADE-L using this config, it gave the following error:

***Q1: Instance(of type bjt) requires the use of a model***.

Need help.

I'd also like to mention that I'm using the spectre tool.

Comment: You need to learn how to import a model - it might be as simple as copying the text from the file onto a "model" sheet in your project.

Comment: This is explained in the manuals, from ADE use Setup => Model Libraries and select the model file for your transistor.

Answer (score 1):

The NCSU PDK has a circuit symbol for a BJT for schematic design, but not for simulation.  You did not mention the version that you are using of the NCSU PDK, but as of 1.4.x, the lateral BJT could not be simulated.  I assume you are trying to make a lateral BJT because of two things:  the model ami06n, and the NCSU tool kit targets the C5 process, which is now owned by ON:  http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/content.do?id=16693 that does not have an explicit BJT.

If you want to lay these out, this will get you started:
http://users.ece.gatech.edu/phasler/Courses/ECE4430/Unit3/BJTTechnology.pdf
I use a ploy ring structure that is different from what is in those slides.  Also, you need to be mindful to keep the lat-BJT in a guard ring and away from t-gates or you will likely make a parasitic SRC.